# How to get an api key for GetAround

Tags: rest, curl

Ok, I know this is a stupid question, but I just need help with a stupid problem. I cannot for the life of me figure out where the right place is to ask this question.

I am trying to write a tool that gets data from my account on GetAround. I noticed that there's quite a bit of API documentation on https://api.getaround.com/ but it assumes that I already know how to get an API key. IIUC, ordinarily you would request an API key from the service, usually with some developer portal.

Can anybody tell me how to get an API key from GetAround? What obvious thing am I missing?